# xcode with Swift: is it possible to show a table view only at the bottom half of the view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I use a TabBar view to present different views, the first tab presents a list of questions (see the screenshot 1). When a question is tapped, the question detail view will be shown. For the question detail view, I wish to display the question detail at the top half of the view while displaying a list of the answers in a tableview at the bottom half (see the screenshot 2).
**Screenshot 1:**
[image: screenshot 1]

**Screenshot 2:**
[image: screenshot 2]

I made the following view controller for the question detail view:

```
class QuestionDetailViewController: UITableViewController {

    var question: Question!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionBody: UILabel!
    // var answers = [Answer]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        questionTitle.text = question.title
        questionBody.text = question.content

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3 //answers.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("answerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // let answer = answers[indexPath.row] as! Answer
        cell.textLabel!.text = "answer content here"
        return cell
    }

}
```

But when a question is tapped, I got the following error from the `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method that pushes the question detail view.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "questionDetailsBoard" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

This made me wonder if it is possible to only display the table view at the bottom half of the view.

Comment: You need to take a `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController` for question details part. Keep a `UITableView` in the bottom half and other UILabels in the upper half.

Comment: thanks, that works for me!